# Delete commands after trigger

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Recently i discover a new way to chose if the trigger should be deleted or not, here is it: (need to put this in main.py)

```
@client.before_invoke  # Delete commands after trigger
async def delete_command(ctx):
    d_command = True  # True=Yes/False=No
    if d_command:
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        return
```

however i wanna create a exception to this (make a specific command not be deleted even with d_command set to True)
example: 8ball clearly the command in this case should't be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `ctx.command.name` is equal to '8ball' an then just return

```py
@client.before_invoke  # Delete commands after trigger
async def delete_command(ctx):
    d_command = True  
    if ctx.command.name == "8ball":
        return
    elif d_command:
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Docs link:

- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)
- [`ctx.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.command)
- [`commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command)
- [`command.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.name)

Comment: oh, i cant test it right now - does it give an error?

Comment: is `8ball` the actuall command name? if not you might have to change this ;)

Comment: ohhhh the name is _8ball, 8ball is one of the aliases. Now working fine! Thnks friend